# IllegalStateException: Location is not set when running jar file

Tags: java, fxml, illegalstateexception

I wrote a program which works fine when running it in IntelliJ.

I created artifact, so I can also run it from executable jar, but it doesn't work.

GUI of my app simply does not appear. I run the jar from command line and I got `IllegalStateException: Location is not set` which is probably caused by this class:

```
public class SingleIcon extends AnchorPane {

    public SingleIcon() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getResource("../resources/fxml/SingleIcon.fxml"));
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../resources/fxml/SingleIcon.fxml"));

        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try { 
            fxmlLoader.load(); 
        } catch (IOException exception) { 
            throw new RuntimeException(exception); 
        }
    }

    @FXML private void initialize() {}
}
```

SingleIcon is created multiple times during initialization of the program.

The `System.out.println()` line gives me this line numerous times:

```
file:/C:/Users/Patryk/IdeaProjects/Battleships/out/production/Battleships/battleships/resources/fxml/SingleIcon.fxml
```

Running jar `(java -jar app.jar)` from command line gives me `null` and `IllegalStateException`.

I checked path I pass to `getResource()` method and it is correct - I have to get back by one directory and then go through to SingleIcon.fxml. Anyway, it wouldn't work in IntelliJ if the path was not correct.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a relative path in your call to `getResource`. This is returning null which is causing the exception. If the resources are packaged with the jar simply call it like this

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/resources/fxml/SingleIcon.fxml"));
```

Notice the preceding forward slash.

Comment: It doesn't work either. I get the same error when running from command line, additionaly I can't run the app in IntelliJ - it gives me same the same error as command line.

Comment: In the JAR file, is there a SingleIcon.fxml file?

Comment: I think so, this is how I created artifact:
File -> Project structure -> Artifacts -> Add -> JAR -> From module with dependencies. Then I pointed my main class and checked JAR files from libraries: extract to the target JAR. Maybe I made some mistake here, I'm not sure I created artifact properly.

Comment: Try opening your JAR file as a ZIP using something like WinRAR or 7-zip to check if the files exist

Comment: Yes, it exists. The path is: battleships/resources/fxml/SingleIcon.fxml. Compiled SingleIcon.class is in battleships/model/SingleIcon.class.

Comment: Ok, so change the string to `/battleships/resources/fxml/SingleIcon.fxml` and that should fix it.

The string is the path to the resource with a `/` prepended.

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you very much! I knew it had to be some stupid mistake, I don't get all this relative path etc. things...